# "Creating default object from empty value" error for Customer phone and email in Quickbooks api

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I had been using the intuit's Quickbooks Api to connect with the admin panel. 
Currently using only to create a Customer record from the Admin panel. I'm able to add **Name**, **Company Name** but not able to add Phone and Email details. Following is the code:

```
function qb_insert($name,$company,$phone,$email){   
    $requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(QB_accessToken,QB_accessTokenSecret,QB_consumerKey,QB_consumerSecret);
    $serviceType= IntuitServicesType::QBO;
    $serviceContext = new ServiceContext(QB_realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);
    $dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);

    $customerObj = new IPPCustomer(); 
    $customerObj->Name = $name; 
    $customerObj->CompanyName = $company; 
    $customerObj->GivenName = $name;
    $customerObj->DisplayName = $name;
    $customerObj->PrimaryEmailAddr->Address = $email;
    $customerObj->PrimaryPhone->FreeFormNumber = $phone;
    $resultingCustomerObj = $dataService->Add($customerObj);
    return $resultingCustomerObj;
}
```

If you take a closer look,I had been using `PrimaryPhone, Phone,AlternatePhone, Mobile, PrimaryEmailAddr` but none of them works. 
A Customer is being created with only `Name and Company name`.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to answer my own question :P

I didn't find this easily. 
I took a closer look over the output given by (SELECT * FROM Customer) using Query of the Api and got the following:

`...blah...blah
"PrimaryPhone" :{
    "FreeFormNumber" : 74114xxxxx
}
...blah...blah`

This is the reason why I started to use `$customerObj->PrimaryPhone->FreeFormNumber`.

I searched through the API code for `FreeFormNumber` and found `IPPTelephoneNumber` class under which this is created.

Similarly `IPPEmailAddress` class for Email.

**Finally,** got it worked doing the following:

For Phone

`$customerObj->PrimaryPhone = new IPPTelephoneNumber();
 $customerObj->PrimaryPhone->FreeFormNumber = $phone;`

And For Email

`$customerObj->PrimaryEmailAddr = new IPPEmailAddress();
$customerObj->PrimaryEmailAddr->Address = $email;`

PS: A sincere request to any big products who provide APIs please provide a relevant example instead of loads and loads of DOCS!